# Aurelia fetch AWS API Gateway give opaque response

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, fetch, aurelia

I have an AWS API Gateway that accepts a POST request to trigger a Lambda function and return the result.

I have tried to enable CORS on the API.

```
const url = 'XXX'
@inject(HttpClient)
export class App {
  constructor(http) {
    http.configure(config =>
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl(url)
        .withDefaults({
          // mode: 'no-cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json'
          }
        }));

    this.http = http;

    this.http.fetch('/', { method: 'post', body: {data: 'XXXX'} })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

The result is:

```
body:null
bodyUsed:false
headers:Headers
ok:false
status:0
statusText:""
type:"opaque"
url:""
```

This I have tried:

- Enabling the Lambda Proxy
- Enabling CORS
- Using an OPTIONS endpoint for preflight response.

I even tried to change the Lambda function to:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, {"success": true});
}
```

to make sure that the lambda function "works" (and it does as seen in Cloudwatch)

Comment: As far as I understand the requirements in the Fetch spec, the only way you could end up with `type:"opaque"` is if the [**response tainting**](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-response-tainting) for the request is `opaque`. And the only way you could end up with the response tainting being `opaque` is if the request mode is `no-cors`. So do you actually have `mode: 'no-cors'` commented out in the your code? If not then it would seem that some other part of your code must be setting the request mode to `no-cors`. Otherwise there’s no way you’d be getting `type:"opaque"`.

Comment: (You basically never want to intentionally sent `mode: 'no-cors'` on a fetch request (unless maybe you’re doing something with Service Worker caching). If you do you won’t be able, for example, to set `Content-type' : 'application/json'` and have it work. And even if when it otherwise “works” you’re just going to get a response back that your JavaScript code isn’t going to be able to do anything with other than cache it.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker Yes, I have commented out the `mode: 'no-cors'` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to enable CORS in Aurelia http, because Aurelia Fetch client's default is CORS. I would say that the problem is 99% on your AWS API Gateway. Have you tried to GET to your endpoints from another App? (for example using Postman chrome extension). Does it work?